# Wrapping Open API to detect errors at compile time

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL, you can waste a lot of time because of this (in particular):

```
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // OK
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES); // WRONG but compiles
    glPolygonMode(GL_LINE, GL_FRONT_AND_BACK); // WRONG but compiles
```

Finding such errors may take some time.

**What I would like:**

1. Wrap the C API with C++;
2. Enforce strong parameters checking to detect such errors at compile time;
3. Provide a way to easily "remove" the C++ wrapper to use plain OpenGL C API when we know that everything is alright (in RELEASE mode for example).

**What I tried:**

1. Wrap OpenGL calls with a macro function adding some prefix like `MY_`
2. Wrap OpenGL functions parameters with a macro function adding a prefix like MY_##type::MY_##name so that OpenGL "global" defines are transformed into local enums;
3. Define the equivalent functions and enums.

**What I got:**

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TRFUNC(func) MY_##func
#define TRPARAM(type, name) MY_##type::MY_##name

enum MY_FACE{MY_GL_FRONT_AND_BACK};
enum MY_MODE{MY_GL_POINT, MY_GL_LINE, MY_GL_FILL};

static GLenum tr(MY_FACE face)
{
    if (face == MY_FACE::MY_GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)
        return GL_FRONT_AND_BACK;
}

static GLenum tr(MY_MODE mode)
{
    if (mode == MY_MODE::MY_GL_FILL)
        return GL_FILL;
    if (mode == MY_MODE::MY_GL_LINE)
        return GL_LINE;
    if (mode == MY_MODE::MY_GL_POINT)
        return GL_POINT;
}

// Prefix name because functions names are #defined so will be replaced by preprocessor
static void MY_glPolygonMode(MY_FACE face, MY_MODE mode)
{
    glPolygonMode(tr(face), tr(mode));
}
#else
#define TRFUNC(func) func
#define TRPARAM(type, name) name
#endif
```

And the call is like:

```
TRFUNC(glPolygonMode)(TRPARAM(FACE, GL_FRONT_AND_BACK), TRPARAM(MODE, GL_LINE)); // OK
TRFUNC(glPolygonMode)(TRPARAM(FACE, GL_FRONT_AND_BACK), TRPARAM(MODE, GL_LINES)); // error C2838: 'MY_GL_LINES' : illegal qualified name
TRFUNC(glPolygonMode)(TRPARAM(MODE, GL_LINE), TRPARAM(FACE, GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)); // error C2664: 'void MY_glPolygonMode(MY_FACE,MY_MODE)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'MY_MODE' to 'MY_FACE'
```

This is just "proto solution" to test if it works and how things could be.

**What I want:**

1. Find some existing source code / library for that particular problem (detecting OpenGL errors at compile time);
2. If not, find a cleaner solution because I feel mine, while working, is not elegant.

**What I do NOT want:**

1. A C++ wrapper "hiding" OpenGL C API into some object oriented design. I want to have 1 to 1 mapping;
2. A solution that stick around even when "deactivated". I really want the final code to be pure OpenGL without any additional wrapping functions;

Comment: This could be generated from GL spec files by separate script (i use something like this, but it was intended to check if functions are allowed to be used in GL ES, and it is runtime checking). Other thing is that it wouldn't work with C (because enums are not type-locked in C). Personally, i don't think it worth implementing - KHR_debug will report runtime issues; if you compiled something incorrect - well, it should be tested anyway, and will result in runtime error during tests.

Comment: The main problem is not about testing it at runtime. It is about not making such typos in the first place. It happens all the time and you can easily loose 30 minutes just compiling, running unit tests, then performing manual tests and finding your typo. With a solution like the one I am looking for, you will simply not even have to run your app to see there is a problem.

Comment: Well, it is very bad unit test if it isn't calling actual code... If it does, then you'll get your callback triggered by KHR_debug - just make it part of test conditions. I understand what you want to do, just don't believe it actually a problem. Implementing this compile-time checks could be problematic, especially with support of so many GL extensions (e.g. have to get pointer to function somewhere). Beside that, allowed enums are not the only problem - while runtime checking taking care of all of possible cases.

Comment: Even if it catches only 50% of the typos, I believe it is still worth it. At least, for the fun of implementing it^^

Comment: Well then, take a look at GLEW. They using extensions specifications to generate actual code (with python scripts, as i recall). I use gl.spec and perl script. Or gl.h, i don't actually remember, tried both at some point.

Comment: Thanks, I will see how they are doing that. I am however not sure my initial solution is great. Maybe templates metaprogramming magic could help (I have no clue how it works and if it could be useful in my case though)...

Comment: I really like where you're going with this. It's great to find KHR_debug, too, but unfortunately, it may not be implemented in all versions of OpenGL. It's definitely not implemented in the version I'm using, unfortunately.